# Angular Material Design: Filtering a value from a custom pipe in a mat-table

Tags: angular, observable, material-design, filtering

I am setting up filtering on a Material table. It seems fairly easy if I use a MatTableDataSource and use the filter function. My problem is that I use a custom pipe to add the full name to a column in the table, based on the initials.
The pipe takes the initials, calls a http service and returns the full name from the server. So, in the table I do:

```
<td>{{item.initials | fullNameFromInitials}}</td>
```

The filtering works for the item.initials, because it comes directly from the datasource, but I can't figure out how to filter on the value from the pipe.
The fullNameFromInitials service returns an observable, and I don't really understand observables fully yet.

I tried to call the service directly, instead of using the pipe in the template, and put the returned value in a variable so I can use it when setting up the viewmodel.
That way, it would be a part of the model for the MatTableDataSource, and I should be able to filter on it then.

```
public nameFromInitials: string;

  getFullNameFromInitials(initials: string){
    if (initials != null || initials != undefined) {
      this.myService.getOne('User', initials, 'GetFullNameFromInitials').subscribe(x => this.nameFromInitials = x);
  }
}
```

I also tried to import the pipe directly in the component, and call it there:

```
this.nameFromInitials = this.fullNameFromInitialsPipe.transform('initials');
```

None of these work, which I'm guessing is because of my lack of understanding of observables.

Is there a way to do filtering of a value from a custom pipe, when it is used directly in a mat-table like so?

```
<td>{{item.initials | fullNameFromInitials}}</td>
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more ?

Comment: I think the question is fairly self explanatory.

Comment: What do you need me to explain?

Comment: Have your tried a custom filterPredicate? Mentioned in: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering

Comment: @Wendie. I've tried to set up a predicate to filter specific columns, but I haven't tried it for filtering a custom pipe.

Comment: @Soeren can You make small  working demo on stackblitz ?